# Program crashes when using free() on an array of structure that was created by calloc

Tags: c, crash, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, calloc

I have this function which is using `calloc` to create an array of structure `proposition`. Whenever I try to `free` the resulting array from another fuction, it crashes.

```
proposition* get_matching_propositions(char *pcde, proposition *propositions, int *match_count)
{    
    proposition *matches;
    int         count       = get_count_from_stream(ptf_proposition, sizeof(proposition)),
                cptr_match  = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(propositions[i].cde, pcde) == NULL)
        {
            cptr_match++;
        }
    }

    matches = (proposition*) calloc (cptr_match, sizeof(propositions));
    assert(matches != NULL);

    cptr_match = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(propositions[i].cde, pcde) == NULL)
        {
            matches[cptr_match] = propositions[i];
            cptr_match++;
        }
    }
    *match_count = cptr_match;
    return matches;
}
```

Inside some other function I have:

```
proposition *matches =
    get_matching_propositions(current_question.cde, propositions, &match_count);
free(matches);
```

Then the program crashes with this message :
`Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)   execution time : 1.370 s.`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: `sizeof(propositions)` is the size of a pointer

Comment: `sizeof(propositions)` is not the size of the structure, it's the size of a pointer. So you either want `sizeof(*propositions)` or `sizeof(proposition)`, or even `sizeof(*matches)`. The difference between what you have and `sizeof(propositions)` is just the `s` at the end, which is a good indiction that you need to adopt a better naming convention to avoid typos like this in the future.